# Measurable functions on product space

Tags: measure-theory, products

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{H}), (E, \mathcal{E})$ and $(F,\mathcal{F})$ be measurable spaces. Let $(E \times F, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$ be a product space. Define the following three functions:

1. $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (E,\mathcal{E})$
2. $Y: (\Omega, \mathcal{H} \rightarrow (F,\mathcal{F})$
3. $Z = (X,Y): (\Omega, \mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (E \times F, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$

Now, I am trying to show that the following:
$X:(\Omega,\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (E,\mathcal{E})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (F,\mathcal{F})$ are measurable $\Leftrightarrow (X,Y): (\Omega,\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (E \times F, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$ is measurable.

Here is my current work:

$(\Rightarrow):$

Since X and Y are both measurable, we have
\begin{align*}
Z^{-1}(E \times F) &= \{w \in \Omega: Z(w) \in E \times F\}\\
&= \{w \in \Omega:(X(w),Y(w)) \in E \times F\}\\
&= \{w \in \Omega: X(w) \in E\text{ and }Y(w) \in F\}\\
&= \{w \in \Omega: X(w) \in E \} \cap \{w \in \Omega: Y(w) \in F\}\\
&= X^{-1}(E) \cap Y^{-1}(F),
\end{align*}
so the function $Z(w)$ is measurable for any $w \in \Omega$.

$(\Leftarrow):$ On this part I'm stuck so I just wrote out my assumptions and what I want to show:

We assume $Z(w)$ is measurable, so we have $Z^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{H}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}.$ We need to show that X and Y are measurable, i.e. $X^{-1}(A) \in \Omega$ for all $B \in \mathcal{E}$ and $Y^{-1}(C) \in \Omega$ for all $C \in \mathcal{F}.$

How can I finish the rest of this proof? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything like  of this in my book (Probability and Stochastics by Cinlar)

Comment: You should really not use $E$ and $F$ to denote arbitrary sets in $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$. This looks like it's causing you some confusion. Also what is $w$ and what does it mean when you say $Z(w)$ is measurable or that $X^{-1}(w)\in\Omega$?

Comment: Yeah well, you can't use $E$ to denote the state space and at the same time be arbitrary sets of your sigma-algebra.

Comment: $w$ is some element in the set $\Omega$. E and F are also sets, which together with their $\sigma$-algebras make up the two measurable spaces. Where am I using them as arbitrary sets of my sigma-algebra?

Comment: If $w\in\Omega$ then quantities such as $X^{-1}(w)$ makes no sense. You're using $E$ and $F$ as arbitrary elements in the statement "$Z^{-1}(E\times F)\in\Omega$ for all $E\in\mathcal{E}$, $F\in\mathcal{F}$", no? Actually, the statement "$Z^{-1}(E\times F)\in \Omega$" makes no sense since $Z^{-1}(E\times F)$ is a subset of $\Omega$ (this has nothing to do with measurability). That $Z$ is measurable means $Z^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{H}$ for all $A\in\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Ahh, I agree..I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: The component function can be obtained by composition of Z and coordinate projection function. It is trivia to prove that the coordinate projection is measurable, so the composition is measurable (Proposition 2.5 of Erhan Çınlar's "Probability and Stochastics").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Given $e \in \mathcal E$ (that is $e$ is a subset $e \subseteq E$, note, as Stefan commented, that you named the whole set $E$ already) we have 
$$ Z^{-1}(e \times F) = \{ \omega \in \Omega \mid Z(\omega) \in e \times F \} 
   = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in e \} $$
(as $Y(\omega) \in F$ holds because of $Y \colon \Omega \to F$). Along the same lines $$ Z^{-1}(E \times f) = Y^{-1}(f), \quad f \subseteq F $$

Comment: I'm a little bit confused - is your hint for the $\Leftarrow$ part of the proof?

Comment: Yes it is ... if $Z$ is measurable, $Z^{-1}(e \times F) \in \mathcal H$ for each $e \in \mathcal E$. As $X^{-1}(e) = Z^{-1}(e \times F)$ this implies ...

Comment: this implies that $X^{-1}(e) \in \mathcal{H}$. Then I could do the same for $Y^{-1}(f)$.

Hope it understood it correctly..
Also, should I write $e \subseteq E$ or $e \in E$? Since technically $e$ is a subset, using $\in$ feels a little wrong.

Comment: $e$ is a subset of $E$, but an element of $\mathcal E$.